# Problem using if statement with ArrayList

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist

I am using an if statement as shown below,

```
if(sign.size()==0)
```

Here `sign` is of the type `ArrayList<Character>`

I am trying to add a `char` to the `ArrayList`

But its not working. Is there anything wrong with my if statement?

I also tried the same with an `ArrayList<doubler>`, this time I could get into the if statement.

Is there anything wrong with the if statement?

Comment: You need to be MUCH clearer with your questions and post COMPILABLE code that reproduces your problem. Right now we have absolutely no idea what you're doing or what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

I am having very difficult time understanding what you are saying, but it sounds like you are trying to figure out how to increase the list capacity. You do not need to manually do this. Simply add items using add() method and the list will re-size itself as appropriate.

Comment: i want to get in the if only if i have 1 char in the array... but i does not get in to the if.... way if i have only one index

Answer (score 0):

Try `if(sign.isEmpty())` instead. Also make sure you you're using good code style with {'s where needed.  ArrayLists will adjust their own size to accommodate what you put in, so I'm not sure you even need this check.

Answer (score 0):

You commented on an answer and said,

> i want to get in the if only if i have 1 char in the array... but i does not get in to the if.... way if i have only one index

If you want to enter the `IF` only when there is one char, then you'd want
`IF(sign.size() == 1){
...some code
}`

Otherwise, if you want to enter the `IF` when size is 0, use isEmpty.

Answer (score 0):

As you said

> I want to get in the if only if I have
>   1 char in the array... but it does not
>   get in to the if.... what if i have
>   only one index?

If you are trying to enter the if statement only when there is only one `char` in the ArrayList then you can use

```
if(sign.size() == 1){
    //your code
}
```

The condition will only be true when the size of the `ArrayList` is equal to 1.